# IntelliJ: How to preview differences in incoming changes?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA offers a `Preview Diff` for outgoing changes that shows a compressed view of the changes. I cannot find an equivalent for **incoming changes**. Each single file must be compared in an extra window against the former revision or the local change.

As a former Eclipse user I liked the Eclipse Synchronization view, which seems faster than the IntelliJ incoming diff.

Do you know any plugin or even some other VCS system (I am using SVN) that is offering an easier "quick diff"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also missing this feature,
in [youtrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com) I've found two submits:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-121195
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100234
Both submits habe be assigned for three week, wait and see..

Comment: I guess this will be the final answer. Sad to hear, but: Thanks!